# Can i make a render like what i see in my viewport?

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, 3d-view

I'd like to know if I can make a render that looks like what I see in my viewport.

Viewport screenshot :

[image]

Render :

[image]

With the viewport, I lose a lot of details and I have quite some noise, but sometimes it gives a feeling of a "painted" image, which I really like on some projects.
It is most noticeable on the sphere and the edges of the room.

Anyway, I can render what I have in my viewport directly?

Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Take a screenshot of it!

Comment: Have you tried to use the same number of samples and noise threshold in render and viewport? (*Cycles > Sampling* section) The viewport usually has a lower number of samples and a higher noise threshold for the denoiser (Blender 3). With these settings, you get a quick result, but fewer details.

Comment: Yes, i tried to match the samples settings, even trying 1 sample for the render, still not the same.

Comment: Here, the images are with the 5 samples settings. ( and no, screenshot won't do for animations )

Comment: Ok, and the first screenshot is in "Render" shading mode, not "Material Preview"? Do you use any modifiers that have different settings for viewport & render? -- Well, plan B: You can still try what @BlenderMaster15 said and use the menu "View > Viewport Render Image" or "... > .... Animation" to render what you see in the viewport. Just turn off the overlays before you do so.

Comment: The first screenshot is indeed in render shading mode and my settings are the same between viewport and render. If i disable the "denoise" function in the viewport, i have a total different render in shading mode that looks like more the final render.

Comment: I'm trying the "Viewport Render Animation" and i just have a black screen. I can see the number of frame calculated from 1 to 250. But i only see nothing but black screen :/

Comment: Well, it goes blackscreen only in shading mode, not in material preview... don't know why yet

Comment: Oh sorry. Yes, it's because you use Cycles for rendering. Looks like the *Viewport Render* doesn't work with it.

Comment: Can you provide a demo file at https://blend-exchange.com/? I still wonder why your outputs differ.

Comment: Sure ! [<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=qrsAoNKg" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/qrsAoNKg/)

Comment: If you set *Render Properties (Cycles) > Sampling > Render > Denoise > Passes* to *Albedo* then it looks closer to the viewport render which has the same setting. But it is only similar, not 100% the same.

Comment: That did it ! I get 100% the same image ! Thank you a lot ! I'm still new to blender, started a few weeks ago so... Tanks !

Comment: Hi @JimRolls and Blunder, could you wrap up your discussion and result in an answer? It would be easier for other users to profit from your „journey“ towards a solution.

Comment: Yes, sorry but how do i do that ?

Comment: @JimRolls Just post a summary, the settings, and a screenshot as answer to this question. You can answer and even accept your own question.

Answer (score 1):

To exactly match what you see in the viewport into the final render :

- set Render Properties the same way you're viewport's set.
- for me, the important part was the denoiser section.

[image]